# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp

Tags: python, time, timestamp

While converting a `panda` object to a timestamp, I am facing this strange issue.

Train['date'] value is like `01/05/2014` which I am trying to convert into linuxtimestamp.

My code:

```
Train = pd.read_csv("data.tsv", sep='\t') # use TAB as column separator
Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socratis.py", line 11, in <module>
    Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62658)
  File "socratis.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp())
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
```

Answer (score 14):

[to_datetime seems to be deprecated.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_datetime.html) Use `to_pydatetime()` instead...

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp), which was added in Python 3.3. Pandas itself isn't involved.

> *N.B.* `.timestamp()` will localize naive timestamps to the computer's UTC offset. To the contrary, suggestions in this answer are timezone-agnostic.

Since pandas [uses nanoseconds internally](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) (numpy [datetime64[ns]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)), you should be able to do this even with Python 2:

```
Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).value / 1e9
```

Or be more explicit wtih something like this (from the datetime docs):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def posix_time(dt):
    return (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)

Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).apply(posix_time)
```

Answer (score 4):

The method to_datetime will return a `TimeStamp` instance.  I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish by the lambda function, but it appears you are trying to convert some object to a `TimeStamp`.

Try removing the apply section so it looks like this:

`Train['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Train['date'])`

Comment: if we do this, it does not convert date into linux timestamp. Which I need

Comment: Try this. if it works ill update the  answer:

`Train['timestamp'] = time.mktime(pd.to_datetime(Train['date']).timetuple())`

Comment: which python do you use? Iam getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
`